# Efficient SQL query to show data points from one table that do not exist in multiple other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list of users (AGENTS) and a list of their areas in another table (AREAS). Users will put data into multiple tables (TBL1, TBL2, TBL3, etc) depending on the type of data that it is. I am trying to find an efficient query that will show me which users have not put data into any table in certain time frames.

The Query I have works, but times out on larger databases. I am looking for help to make this more efficient.

```
Select AREA, USERID 
FROM AGENTS left outer join AREAS on AGENTS.AID=AREAS.AID
    WHERE USERID not in (Select distinct USERID FROM AGENTS 
        UNION Select Distinct USERID FROM TBL1 Where Datestamp between '1/1/2023' and '8/18/2023' 
        UNION Select Distinct USERID FROM TBL2 Where Datestamp between '1/1/2023' and '8/18/2023'
        UNION Select Distinct USERID FROM TBL3 Where Datestamp between '1/1/2023' and '8/18/2023'
        UNION Select Distinct USERID FROM TBL4 Where Datestamp between '1/1/2023' and '8/18/2023'
        UNION Select Distinct USERID FROM TBL5 Where Datestamp between '1/1/2023' and '8/18/2023'
        UNION Select Distinct USERID FROM TBL6 Where Datestamp between '1/1/2023' and '8/18/2023') Order by AREA
```

Comment: All those `DISTINCT`s and `UNION`s are overkill. Why force the data engine to get the `DISTINCT` values from each table and then `DISTINCT` all those results? A `NOT IN` against the `UNION ALL`'d would be much more efficient as it doesn't matter if the value appears in the tables once or one thousand times.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I thought it would be less intensive with the distincts. I will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select AREA, USERID 
FROM AGENTS...
    WHERE USERID not in (Select distinct USERID FROM AGENTS ...
```

- How can you find agents.userid that are NOT IN agents.userid? As I don't understand that part of your existing query I shall omit it below.

Whilst I can't be certain the following is better, another, often surprisingly efficient, way to do tests of this nature is to use EXISTS or NOT EXISTS e.g:

```
Select
   area, userid
FROM AGENTS 
where   not exists (select null from TBL1 where tbl1.USERID = agents.USERID)
    and not exists (select null from TBL2 where tbl2.USERID = agents.USERID)
    and not exists (select null from TBL3 where tbl3.USERID = agents.USERID)
    and not exists (select null from TBL4 where tbl4.USERID = agents.USERID)
    and not exists (select null from TBL5 where tbl5.USERID = agents.USERID)
    and not exists (select null from TBL6 where tbl6.USERID = agents.USERID)
```

Please don't worry about the `select null` you could use `select 1` or `select *` if you prefer. When using EXISTS the sub-query select clause is quite unimportant as the existence of a row is determined by the from & where clauses.

Now to this you may also add your date range filter, BUT in SQL Server the best way to handle date literals is NOT m/d/y (which relies on a server default setting to work at all). I urge you to use yyyymmdd instead (yes without any delimiters). i.e.

```
Select
   area, userid
FROM AGENTS 
where   not exists (select null from TBL1 where tbl1.USERID = agents.USERID Where Datestamp between '20230101' and '20230818')
    and not exists (select null from TBL2 where tbl2.USERID = agents.USERID Where Datestamp between '20230101' and '20230818')
    and not exists (select null from TBL3 where tbl3.USERID = agents.USERID Where Datestamp between '20230101' and '20230818')
    and not exists (select null from TBL4 where tbl4.USERID = agents.USERID Where Datestamp between '20230101' and '20230818')
    and not exists (select null from TBL5 where tbl5.USERID = agents.USERID Where Datestamp between '20230101' and '20230818')
    and not exists (select null from TBL6 where tbl6.USERID = agents.USERID Where Datestamp between '20230101' and '20230818')
```

For any further performance tuning we would require execution plans and knowing all the indexes you have on all the tables involved.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is some great knowledge and I appreciate it. To Answer your question I didn't properly identify that USERID exists in both Agents and in the tbl's. Essentially we're just looking to see which agents haven't entered data into the tbl's based off of the agent list.